# Is there any possible to limit only 10 message number from PHP imap_search() result for pagination purpose?

Tags: php, gmail, imap, mailboxer

I am working on a mailbox module, almost all kind of mailbox process were completed, finally, i set search functionality, search list is working well, but some searching keywords return huge number of msg_no from imap_search function, if it is return more number of msg_no it take long time, so i decide to make pagination in search results,

Here, i have search lot of results, there is no possibility to limit a number of msg_no from imap_search(); search function return all msg_no based on matched criteria

So kindly assist me to achieve those things

Comment: Does this answer your question? [imap\_search limit the number of messages returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177306/imap-search-limit-the-number-of-messages-returned)

Comment: There is no built in way to search with pagination or limiting to n results.  You can limit it by say, only searching 1000 messages at a time (eg, `SEARCH n-1000:n OTHER-STUFF`) or the last several days, or whatever, but if what you’re searching for is rare, that’ll take much longer to get enough results.

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, i have the same issue, but the green checked answer is not a solution : - (

Comment: Thanks @Max , Now I search 'sales' keyword it take 3 mins for search from six kind of criteria, but in gmail, it return the same keyword within 5 secs, if i search some keyword with particular number of message, if that keyword doesn't exist on that it will return empty, but that keyword match with other part  number of messages, that technique is not a better solution, I just want to know that how gmail fetch rapidly from search results with pagination?

Comment: If you're using gmail, you can use the [gmail search language](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions#extension_of_the_search_command_x-gm-raw), but I don't know if that's available from PHP IMAP.  Or, don't use IMAP, it is not well suited for server side searching.  Most severs are not optimized for that since end user clients tend to just download everything and do local searching.  Gmail has a wide variety of HTTP based APIs.

Comment: Great, thanks for your assistance @Max